# Find The Real Location Of Rar File After launching a Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, rar

Think I have a compressed file named "Target.rar" and its location is Desktop, inside it I have put a batch script. When I open the rar file (without extracting it) I can see the files inside. If I double click my batch script, winRAR first extract all files into temp folder and will run my batch script from there, so the root directory will be Temp folder, But I need to do something on .rar file location (which is desktop here).

How to get real location of Rar File?

Comment: Have you tried `pushd ..` and `popd`, to hop up one level in the directory structure? Or if you know that it's the desktop you want to touch, use `pushd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop`.

Comment: @Mogsdad thanks for reply, no Desktop location was an example, it can be every where, can you explain a little more about pushd and popd commands?

Comment: You'll find lots of explanations if you use the search terms "pushd popd". These are used to manage a stack of directory locations - basically 'pushd' first pushes the current directory onto a stack, then does a chdir (cd) to a new location you've provided. To climb up to a parent dir, 'pushd ..' works. Use 'popd' to pop the previous location off the stack, and cd there.

Comment: If you set your winrar configuration with a blank "folder for temporary files", it will use the "current directory" (where the rar is) for temporary files and directories. That's fine if you're doing all this just for yourself, but you can't control other people's settings. If you're using the winrar to distribute software, I think you should look into creating a self-extracting SFX with setup=<yourbatch.cmd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for the rar file if you are confident that you know there won't be any other files with the same name.

```
dir /b /s C:\Target.rar
```

Obviously if you know how deep you have to look you can narrow down the search path, and save some time.

If you know it will at least be under `C:\Users\%username%` then you can use

```
dir /b /s C:\Users\%username%\Target.rar
```